# RF Transmission Loss

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, electric-circuits, classical-electrodynamics, radio-frequency

I am aware that an **ideal** 3rd order circuit with R=0 will oscillate forever, but even this this is not true. Power is dissipated through the em waves.

How does one calculate the losses due to these emissions?

Comment: I don't really understand your question, the fields carry Power and thus you lose Power this way. Could you measure the field strength and possible radiation pattern? Or did i misunderstand you completely?

Comment: Exactly, I want a way to calculate the power lost due to rf transmission. I would like a mathematical model. I understand practically it is done with software and actual measurments.

Comment: Then i guess you'd need to look at non-ideal equations for the oscillator in question where there should be loss-terms included.

Comment: post this on the amateur radio stack exchange- the equation exists and those guys know it. and they are helpful people.

Comment: You might find guidance on how to think about this type of problem here:  [A Capacitor Paradox](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/d7f5/d873ddb169c26385a0470f5b0bb2050fd293.pdf) - *"In the present example, some of the energy in the electrostatic field of the initially charged capacitor “escapes” from the circuit in the form of electromagnetic radiation. Hence, we should examine the possibility that radiation carries away a significant fraction of the “missing” energy."*  Essentially, you need to model this with the addition of a resistance - a radiation resistance.

Comment: @AlfredCentauri That is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!